# How to make my save button first disabled then enabled it after 5 entries of data in a table and save it in database afterwards using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

```html
<table id="facilitytable" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ __('Facility ID')}}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Facility Name')}}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Course Name')}}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Province')}}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Action')}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($data as $row)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $row->facilityid }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->facility }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->coursename }}</td>
      <td>{{ $row->province }}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="addtorankingbtn">
          <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="removetorankingbtn">
          <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table table-striped" id="rankingtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ __('Order')}}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Facility Name')}}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Course Name')}}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Province')}}</th>
      <th>{{ __('Action')}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

this are my facilitytable and rankingtable. i will get my data from facilitytable transferring or cloning it to my rankingtable. if there are 5 entries of data in my rankingtable then my save button will be enabled which from the start disabled. if my save button is now enabled then it can store/save data from my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function like this:

```
function hideShowSave(saveButton) {
    saveButton.disabled = (document.querySelectorAll("#rankingtable tr").length < 5)
}
```

You will need to properly pass the correct HTML element to this function, which was not part of your example and you need to call this function at the end of both your `addtorankingbtn` and `removetorankingbtn` button click handler functions.

EDIT

You can get/pass `saveButton` by querying for it via `document.getElementById("savebtn")`.

Comment: i forgot to put it but this is my save button

Comment: <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="savebtn" disabled="true">

Comment: @DanDanSevilla thanks for the info, I have edited my answer accordingly.